# Opening a push notification from the app does not mark the inbox notification as read

Tags: bug, ios-app

If I open the Stack Overflow app via a push notification for an inbox item, and then open Stack Overflow on the web after the page has loaded in the app, the specific inbox item from the push notification is still marked as unread.

Tested with a comment reply.  I imagine this is due to the inbox item not counting as "read" until you go back to the inbox tab.

- App Version: 1.0.1 (1.0.1.2) beta from TestFlight
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: I've noticed this on occasion with the Android app but never really read too far into it.  Reply if you think that's worth testing.  Either way, consider this validation for your further smoke test.

Comment: Yeah I think I'm going to try and test this more actively, especially with the pre-release builds.

Answer (score 1):

This is something we wanted to do but have no good solution for.

The problem is that the global inbox's behavior is driven by the web site's behavior where your feed will always have a block of zero or more unread items followed by zero or more read items, never an unread-read-unread pattern.  Having the mobile inbox be able to mark a single item as read and behave slightly inconsistently with the web is something I'm all in favor of, but 1) that feeling is not universal and 2) there are assumptions and optimizations throughout the codebase based on the "never unread-read-unread" pattern which would be a big project to review and address.

That leaves us with a few options:

- **Mark all inbox items as read when opening a push notification with a target post.** I don't want to do this because it discards information before the user gets a chance to see it.
- **Have all notifications take you to the inbox and not the linked post.** This will let users see all the unread items but then they have to tap on the inbox item to see the actual post.  This is what we've been doing in the Stack Exchange app and I don't really like it.
- **Take the user to the post and not mark the inbox as read.** That's what we're doing today.  The user still has to return to the inbox to mark it as read, but the notifications are more functional and there's no information discarded.

Comment: "No good solution is right." And to think I've been grumbling over the inconsistent behavior of marking Discord notifications as read! (Swiping one sometimes clears only itself, sometimes it clears other notifications for the same channel, other times other notifications for the same server, sometimes it clears *a completely random notification*--could be a DM, could be a message from another server entirely) and navigating to a channel with a notification while the app is open doesn't clear the notification either (unlike, say, viewing my Gmail inbox).